# Looking for regex to add new line before numbers in the form of (1) in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string as following:

> test test (1) abvczbvczx (2) sdafadfdsafmda sf a(3) asfsdfadsfdasf a (4) asdf)!
> dsafadfdasfdas (5) abcde

I am looking for the correct regex to make it into:
test test

> (1) abvczbvczx
>
> (2) sdafadfdsafmda sf a
>
> (3) asfsdfadsfdasf a
>
> (4) asdf)! dsafadfdasfdas
>
> (5) abcde

any suggestions?

Comment: What regexes did you try yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace by looking ahead for parenthese with number.

```js
var string = 'test test (1) abvczbvczx (2) sdafadfdsafmda sf a(3) asfsdfadsfdasf a (4) asdf)! dsafadfdasfdas (5) abcde',
    result = string.replace(/(?=\(\d+\))/g, '\n'); // or '<br>' for html

console.log(result);
```